# Add UIViewController object as an observer for NSNotification (all from another UIViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

The title might've thrown you off but here's what I'm trying to do.

Currently, I can successfully broadcast a `NSNotification` message from `WinViewController` to `LevelViewController`.  When `viewDidLoad` gets called in `LevelViewController`, I have the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateLevel:)
                                                 name:@"winToLevel" 
                                               object:nil];
```

However, I want to write this method in my first view controller in the hierarchy called `MainViewController`.  Here's what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)run:(id)sender {
      LevelViewController *levelVC = [[LevelViewController alloc] init];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:levelVC
                                             selector:@selector(updateLevel:)
                                                 name:@"winToLevel" object:nil];
     // create a GameViewController instance
     // push levelVC on the stack without calling viewDidLoad
     // push the GameViewController instance on the stack and call viewDidLoad
}
```

The intention being the `LevelViewController` instance will be the observer, even though (the way I previously had it set up) `viewDidLoad` won't be called.  When I push `WinViewController` on the stack, a notification should be sent to `LevelViewController` and the `updateLevel:` should be called.

I wrote out the method for `updateLevel:` in `LevelViewController`, and currently in `MainViewController` I get a warning saying how `updateLevel:` isn't defined.  That makes sense, but if I did define it in `MainVC`, can `LevelVC` still be an observer, `WinVC` send a notification to `LevelVC`, and `LevelVC` run the method from `MainVC` (via public definition)?

It's a mouthful but if you get what I'm trying to do, let me know if it's possible or if there's a better way of doing it.  Do not ask why I'm doing it for the sake of asking why...ask why if you have an idea in mind, thanks.

*********** UPDATE ************

There are 4 view controllers, and in hierarchical order they are: `MainVC`, `LevelVC`, `GameVC`, `WinVC`.  Here's what I want:

1. Inside `MainVC`, make `LevelVC` instance an observer for a notification.
2. This notification will be broadcasted from `WinVC`.
3. The method definition for `updateLevel:` currently resides in `LevelVC`, but since I am setting up a `NSNotificationCenter` message in `MainVC`, I'm thinking `updateLevel:` should be defined in `MainVC`.

If `updateLevel:` resides in `MainVC`, can I still send a notification from `WinVC` to `LevelVC` and have it run as if `updateLevel:` resides in `LevelVC`?

Comment: do clear your problem that what you want to do ?

Comment: I'll provide an update with what I want

Comment: From your updated question,  MainVC, LevelVC, GameVC, WinVC is the hierarchical right? then why you need to add the observer for levelVC in MainVC ? You can add observer in view did load of levelVC itself is fine. You can send notification from  WinVC to LevelVC

Comment: I know, I mentioned that in the post.  I currently can do that successfully.  Thing is, there's a situation where I go directly from `MainVC` to `GameVC`, adding `LevelVC` to the hierarchy but not calling `viewDidLoad` until `GameVC`.  So, the observer can't be setup in that particular situation, which is why it needs to be done in `MainVC`.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to put `updateLevel:` as a public method that's declared in `LevelVC`.  Thanks though

Comment: You should really use Singleton instead of having notifications firing up all over the places.

Comment: Actually I think I'm going to do that instead.  The only reason for this charade of data passing was to keep track of and change an `NSMutableArray` object to prevent this `UICollectionView` object from loading at the speed of a stumbling sloth.  I'm assuming if I had a singleton for an `NSMutableArray`, I could access it from any view controller and change it from any view controller at will?

Comment: I've been reading around and found that I could make an `NSMutableArray` property in `AppDelegate.h` and just use that "globally"